# android record video without start recording button

Tags: android, android-intent, video-capture

I am trying to find a way to have a timer start the video recorder in android. I open it with an intent but it comes up with the red start recording button. Is there a way I can control the stop and start recording in code (with a timer)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I open it with an intent but it comes up with the red start recording button.

The exact user experience of the video-recording app will vary by app, as there are hundreds, if not thousands, of apps that can respond to `Intent` actions like `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`. For example, whether there is a "red start recording button" or not is up to the developer of the video-recording app.

> Is there a way I can control the stop and start recording in code (with a timer)?

Not if you are launching a third-party app to do the video recording (e.g., `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`). You would have to record the video yourself, using `MediaRecorder`.